# Django project not displaying as expected under domain name

Tags: apache, url, server

My django project is not displaying images, styling, base and the buttons are also not directing users to my other templates, instead it produces a “Bad request” template. It works well in my terminal and on my local machine, in my web using local host port, it looks the way it’s supposed to but it’s different when I upload it to my domain name. [[here is a comparison of how it looks on my local machine and when I upload it on my domain name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc8sN.png)][this is how it looks on my my domain name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnTYz.png)

I bought my hosting VPs plan on hostinger and I’m using the Ubuntu 22.04 server is system. I use PuTTY for my ssh client and also use FileZilla to have a better view of the files in the server.

I already tried uploading my project files through FileZilla, also created a virtual environment and I also tried to code my project through PuTTY(ssh client) but I still receive the same outcome. If you might know what the issue is, please help me fix this.[server files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRnqH.jpg)[server files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNX0i.jpg)[server files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXP0g.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0flb.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PbCO.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.